# extends from MatGridTile class, Component doesn't behave as mat-grid-tile

Tags: angular

I want to create my own `grid-list` and `grid-tiles` with some specific logic and encapsulated templates.

I successfully extend `grid-list` from `MatGridList` and I can use `mat-grid-tiles` inside my `grid-list`.

The issue is - I can't properly extend `GridTile` component using `MatGridTile`, it doesn't work.

link to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-6-fu5z26?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

So mat-grid-list has reference to its children via ContentChildren(), so providing our custom component we can tell mat-grid-list which child component is tile.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-6-nxceea?file=src/app/app.component.ts